# Independence of Cause and Mechanism - Causality

Tags: probability, causality, dag

In causal modelling, we say that $A \longrightarrow B$ if forcing a value change A will influence the likelihood of $B$ while holding all other variables in the system constant. We call this a direct effect. A consequence of this is "independence of cause and mechanism", i.e. $P(A)$ does not influence the conditional $P(B|A)$.

The way I understand it, is that $A$ needs to be fixed in order to observe the cause of $A$ on $B$, and as $A$ is deterministic $P(B|A)$ is independent of the marginal. Is this correct?

**Question:** What exactly means "independence of cause and mechanism". How to show that this is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say this is a matter of terminology. What people in causality mean when they talk about mechanisms (also known as Independent Causal Mechanisms, causal Markov kernels, causal conditionals, etc.) are the "true" causal conditional distributions. In your case, you have only one mechanism $P(B \mid A)$.

As you correctly pointed out, the independence of cause and mechanism is just a way of saying that if you intervene on a variable, you don't change the conditional of downstream variables.

I don't know exactly what do you mean by showing this is true, this is a bit of an "axiom" of causality. But if I was forced to do so, then I would start with the causal Markov condition, which states that a causal graph can be decomposed into the "true" conditional distributions.

Comment: Thanks. For the reply. They way I understood it was that this was a provable property (don’t know how hence my question). But if it is indeed an axiom that that is obviously not necessary. Are there good / canonical examples of why this is intuitively true? I read somewhere that it has a lot of connections to thermodynamics. But I didn’t want to get into that…

Comment: A modified example from Elements of causal inference (https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/elements-causal-inference) is the following. Consider a light emitter A, a surface that reflects light P(B|A), and some form of measurement of the reflected light B. If you change the distribution of the light source (maybe you make the emitted light wider), it will change the measurements of light at the end, B, but certainly does not change the way that the light is reflected, it does not change the mechanism.

Comment: Now, say you modify the surface, P(B|A) so that it absorbs all the light. Then certainly your measurement at the end will be different, but not as a result of a change in the light source, but instead as a change of the way the light is reflected, a change in the mechanism.

Comment: great example. thanks a lot!